# Using Smack API for Instant Messaging in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, xmpp, smack

I want to make an instant messaging app for android. I have the option of using GCM, but I do not want to use it since there may be other platforms that may communicating (web, other mobile platforms etc) with the app.

So, instead of using GCM , I want to use the Smack API (an xmpp library written in java), which uses sockets.

Now, I have a few doubts about it:

- **How smack handles connection drops/reconnects etc**. Is it as 'simple' as GCM? in case of an internet loss, will it automatically reconnect when its available
- **Is it battery efficient ?** Since its listening from its own socket, I would like to know if there will be a massive battery drain or not (it should be listening for messages 24/7 from a background service, and not only while the user is in the app)

Aside of these concerns, I would like to know if there are other (better) ways to have instant messaging. I cannot do sockets from scratch, and would like multiple platforms (thats my I am not a fan of GCM)

Comment: I don't know how Smack API is defined but if you want to use Sockets, as you said, you should be aware of the Activity life cycle on Android. Your activity is "backgrounded" and you lose the socket. If you use a service with a socket you will kill the battery.